# XSLT propagating Parent element into each child in a child list

Tags: xslt-2.0

Am new to XSLT and am just not able to wrap my head around this one.
I have an XML as follows:

```
<root>
  <key>1</key>
  <list>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
  </list>
</root>
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
<root>
    <row>   
        <key>1</key>
         <value>1</value>
    </row>
    <row>   
        <key>1</key>
        <value>2</value>
   </row>         
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not entirely clear, but let's give it a try:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- each first following sibling after <key> -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key/following-sibling::list[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
    <row>
        <!-- the key immediately before the current <list> -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::list/preceding-sibling::key[1]" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

This code assumes a basic understanding of XSLT. And it assumes my understanding that a `list` element is preceded directly by a `key` element and that each `row/value` becomes a `row` with a `value` and the preceding `key`.

You tagged your question XSLT 2.0, but this code works with either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (and in this particular case will not be very different if you tried using the 2.0 features).

Tested with a 1.0 (.NET) and two 2.0 (Exselt and Saxon) processors against the following modified input:

```
<root>
  <key>1</key>
  <list>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
  </list>
  <key>2</key>
  <list>
        <value>55</value>
        <value>66</value>
        <value>77</value>
  </list>
</root>
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
<root>
   <row>
      <key>1</key>
      <value>1</value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <key>1</key>
      <value>2</value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <key>2</key>
      <value>55</value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <key>2</key>
      <value>66</value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <key>2</key>
      <value>77</value>
   </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Your assumptions are perfect. I just wanted to pair a key with each value in its own list and then rename each of them as a row.
Its like moving from a Map of Key to List to a list of key value pairs.

Found another way of doing it as well, will share soon.

Comment: @fsdje glad to hear that, glad it helped